# Storing the value of a GIT command in a Bash variable

Tags: bash, git

I'm trying to create a git alias to automate some of the more annoying Git tasks I need to do. One of which is setting the upstream of a new branch. So I decided to write a Bash script to do it.

However I'm having some difficulties figuring out how to store the return value of a git command in a bash variable.

I have the below code, but it gives me the following errors when I run it.

```
environment: line 0: local: `rev-parse': not a valid identifier
environment: line 0: local: `--abbrev-ref': not a valid identifier
```

What do I need to be able to execute the full `git rev-parse --abbrev-ref HEAD` and store its value in a variable so that I can use it later?

This function is being written in my `.gitconfig`.

```
[alias]
setupstream = "!f() 
            { 
                local branchName=git rev-parse --abbrev-ref HEAD; 
                echo $branchName; 
            }; 

            f"
```

Comment: Additionally, defining an alias which defines a function and then immediately calls that function is kind of pointless.

Comment: @tripleee What do you suggest instead?

Comment: `setupstream = "git rev-parse --abbrev-ref HEAD"` avoids the useless function and the [useless use of `echo`](http://www.iki.fi/era/unix/award.html#echo) which was exacerbated by the [lack of quoting.](/questions/10067266/when-to-wrap-quotes-around-a-shell-variable/27701642)